# For any closed form $a$ with compact support, there exists a form $b$ w.c.s. in the unit ball such that $a-b$ is exact.

Tags: differential-forms, group-cohomology

Let $\alpha$ be a closed (differential) $k$-form with compact support in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. We want to prove that there exists a $l$-form $\beta$ with compact support in the unit ball of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $\alpha-\beta$ is exact.

By Poincaré's lemma, we know that

$$H^{k}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^{n})=\begin{cases}
0 &\text{if } k\neq n\\
\mathbb{R} &\text{if } k=n
\end{cases}$$

which means that any closed $k$-form with compact support is exact for $k\neq n$. If $k\neq n$, taking $\beta=0$ (which is clearly with compact support in the unit ball) gives $\alpha-\beta=\alpha$ which is exact since $\alpha$ is closed.

So, let $\alpha$ be a closed $n$-form with compact support (I shall denote w.c.s.). We want to construct $\beta$ such that there exists an $(n-1)$-form $\eta$ with compact support verifying $$\alpha-\beta=\text{d}\eta$$

Since

$$H^{n}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^{n})=\frac{\text{Closed $n$-forms w.c.s.}}{\text{Exact $n$-forms w.c.s.}}$$

by definition, it means that for any closed $n$-form $\alpha$ w.c.s. and any exact $n$-form $\text{d}\eta$ w.c.s., we have $(\alpha+\text{d}\eta)\in H^{n}_{c}$

I guess we have to use the fact that $\int(\alpha-\beta)=0$ if and only if $\alpha-\beta$ is exact (here, it is the "only if" part that is of interest). So we have to find $\beta$ such that

$$\text{d}\int\alpha=\beta$$

As $\alpha$ is a $n$ form,  we have $\alpha=\sum_{i=1}^{m}f_{i}\text{d}x_{1}\wedge\dots\wedge\text{d}x_{n}$ with $f_{i}\in C^{\infty}_{0}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ for all $i=1,\dots,m$ but it doesn't lead me anywhere.

I also noticed that $\beta$ has to be closed since $\text{d}^{2}=0$ so that

$$\text{d}(\alpha-\beta)=\text{d}^{2}\eta\iff\text{d}\alpha-\text{d}\beta=0\iff \text{d}\beta=0$$

I do not know if there is something I could do with Stokes'theorem here.

I'm lost... Would you have any indication, please?

Comment: You should update your title to correspond to your 2nd, and more descriptive, sentence "We want to prove " - as is, the problem stated in the title (without the unit ball) is vacuous (take $\beta = \alpha$)....

Comment: @peterag Of course, thank you!

Comment: For $k=n$, if you can find any closed, but not exact, form $\omega$ with compact support in the unit ball, aren't you done? i.e., by compact Poincare $\alpha = r \omega$, up to an exact form, for some $r \in \mathbb R$. In fact, the proof of the compact Poincare lemma, at least in Bott and Tu's Differential Forms and Algebraic Topology ( discussion pp 37-40), basically does this (with  support inside an $n$-cube ).  Explicit generator on the bottom  of p 39, followed up with on the top of p 40: "support ... can be made as small as we like."

Comment: @peterag Ok, so I take a generator $\omega$ with support inside the unit ball. I know there exists $r_{\alpha}\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\alpha=r_{\alpha}\omega+\text{d}\eta$. So that $\beta=r_{\alpha}\omega$ works? It makes sense. Thank you. So basically, this exercise is to understand how $H^{\ast}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ works.

Comment: Yes, I think so. In Bott and Tu: if $e:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is of compact support and total integral = 1, their generator is $$ e (x_1) \,dx_1\, e(x_2)\, dx_2 \cdots e(x_n) \,dx_n,$$for $n\ge 1$. (They don't bother writing wedges...)

Comment: @peterag Yes, I have the book under my eyes, but I think I need a little more practice. Thank you for your answer, it was helpful.